# Java-finding a certain text and then write a text after it

Tags: java, file

I need help here

If I have a text like this after opening a file:

```
I am a human
```

I want to add a word(maybe `"awesome"`) in the middle of the word "a" and `"human"`
Example:

```
I am a awesome human
```

Is there a way to do it with java?

I only know how to find which line of the word but not the exact area of the string and write at the area.

Comment: Yest that is possible in java, as in all programming languages which support file IO.

Comment: Yes, you can do it in java. But what have you tried?

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea how to solve my own problem, thus I have done nothing either then reading the line where the text is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder("I am a human");  
int indexOfA = input.indexOf(" a ");  //notice the spaces  
input.insert(indexOfA+1, "awesome ");
```